# Cell data from multiple possibilites from range of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My question is on looking up pay rates from multiple cell options. 
It's based on UK National Minimum Wage, so as staff get older they move up the pay scale.
I am trying to get cells on line 48 to search equivalent column line 2 date of birth (staff Name is line 4) and check Grid AD1 :AG4 to find which rate of pay. The dates AD-AG  are based on TODAY()-365.25* years so are always updated each day.
Hope this explains it.
[My actual spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xghlK.png)

I've tried solution in this, and my attempt is on lien 48 but it reports £0.00 [Excel IF formula for birth date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925637/excel-if-formula-for-birth-date-range)

Comment: In order to let us help you, please the post relevant formula you tried and the relevant data in the body of your question rather than linking to another question and providing a print screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse the order of your dates in columns `AD:AG` so that 16/09/1994 is in column `AD` and 17/09/2003 is in column `AG`.  Use the starting date as the date to look up (so the earliest date is 01/01/1900).

The formula `=HLOOKUP(C2,$AD$2:$AG$4,3,TRUE)` will then return the correct pay.

Note that the **Range_lookup** option is TRUE:

> Optional. A logical value that specifies whether you want HLOOKUP to
>   find an exact match or an approximate match. If TRUE or omitted, an
>   approximate match is returned. In other words, if an exact match is
>   not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is
>   returned. If FALSE, HLOOKUP will find an exact match. If one is not
>   found, the error value #N/A is returned.
>
> If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in the first row of table_array, 
>   HLOOKUP returns the #N/A error value.

Using this:
DOB = 28/05/1951 returns £9.2 as the DOB is less than the next date of 17/09/1995
DOB = 27/06/1998 returns £8.63 as the DOB is less than 17/09/1999.
DOB = 17/09/1999 returns £6.89 as it exactly matches a date on the table.

[HLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-A3034EEC-B719-4BA3-BB65-E1AD662ED95F)

Comment: Thank you so much Darren I cannot tell you how much I appreciate it.
I had to swap rows 2 & 3 round in AD:AG, then it worked.
And nicely simple too
Thank you again!

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to tick the answer as accepted - should be a greyed out tick on the left of my answer somewhere.

Comment: Thanks again Darren, have done. I thought the tick was greyed out to me!